# Updating deep ReactJS state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of items in a ReactJS component state that I'm iterating over to create a form. My question is: How do I best update those items when the fields change?

For example:

```
var items = this.state.foo.bar.items.map(function(item, i) {
    return <input value={item.baz} onChange={??}
});
```

What would my onChange handler look like in this case? Do I change the `item.baz` property directly, then `this.setState(state)`? Seems wrong. I'm looking at the [React immutability helpers](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html), but see how to work with array indexes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the index to update the correct array item by passing it to `onChange` via `bind` and then dynamically building the object to pass to `update`:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function() {
      return  {
        foo : {
          bar : {
            items : [ { baz : 1 }, { baz : 2 }, { baz : 3 } ]
          }
        }
      };
    },
    onChange : function( idx, item, event ) {
      var objForUpdate = { foo: { bar: { items : {} } } };
      objForUpdate.foo.bar.items[ idx ] = { $set : { baz : event.target.value } };
      var newData = React.addons.update( this.state, objForUpdate );
      this.setState( newData );
    },
    render: function() {
      var _this = this;
      var items = this.state.foo.bar.items.map(function(item, i) {
        return <input value={item.baz} onChange={_this.onChange.bind( _this, i, item )}></input>
      });
      return <div>{items}</div>;
    }
});
```

My understanding that this only has an advantage over something like

```
onChange : function( idx, item, event ) {
  item.baz = event.target.value;
  this.setState( this.state );
}
```

if you are going to override [`shouldComponentUpdate`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) and be more selective about when to rerender than every time `this.setState()` is called.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6B4Lx/)

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd just throw this library out there because it was specifically designed for deeply nested react state,

https://github.com/mquan/cortex

You can update items within each component and it automatically trickles up without you having to define callbacks to pass the event up.

Comment: Very cool. I ended up solving the problem way more simply, but that does look interesting.

Comment: You can also use Immutable.js from a Facebook's engineer: http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Comment: Yup that is also great. Lots of stuff going on in this space.