# React setState: set a nested property by string

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing something strange in React, and I think that might be possible to do it but I don't know how.

My goal: update a specific attribute of my component state, that can be a nested attribute. But! I want to update it dynamically (working with a onChange call on a bunch of inputs, don't want to code 30 onChange functions, I want to code a generic one).

**Example that works:**

```
this.state = { value: 0 }
```

Then:

```
var attribute = 'value'
var value = 'myvalue'
this.setState({[attribute]:value})
```

**Example that does not work:**

```
this.state = { nested: { value: 0 } }
```

Then:

```
var attribute = 'nested.value'
var value = 'myvalue'
this.setState({[attribute]:value})
```

I can have potentially as many nesting levels as possible. I want to find a generic and easy to afford method to deal with it.

I created a JSFiddle wich reproduces this problem as I'm trying to implement it, with onchange function: http://jsfiddle.net/n61kv6gy/

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Have you looked into `update`? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008322/updating-deep-reactjs-state

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question yo can try something like this in your onChange function:

```
onChange(value,e) {
  let oldState = this.state.nested.nestedAgain;
  let newState = this.state.nested.nestedAgain;
  newState[value] = e.target.value;

  this.setState({oldState: newState})
}
```

First clone your state, then make a change and at the end update the state.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n61kv6gy/3/)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. That can do partially the job.

Comment: Let's assume that we have a state structured like this:

Comment: (ok thank you stackoverflow auto post comments...)

this state:

{
   value1: 1,
   nested: {
      value2: 2,
      nestedagain: {

   }
}

Comment: Thanks Boky, I updated the JsFiddle with an html representation of the state and initialized it, and I added controls to show you the three cases i can have: http://jsfiddle.net/n61kv6gy/4/

Answer (score 0):

OK stack overflow comment function is very lacky. I answer to @Boky here:

Hi and many thanks for your answer. That does partially the job. How would you modify the code to allow us to bind these 3 properties?

```
{
   value1: 1,
   nested: {
      value2: 2,
      nestedAgain: {
         value3: 3
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: See updated answer. You can maybe try something like that.